Adding CLI arguments to application in dock on Mac OS
I have the following situation: I'd like to add CLI arguments to an app from my dock when it starts.
I've set up an automator action as described in this answer: How do I pass command line arguments to Dock items?
This works, but since the launcher app launches the actual app via a shell script, the actual app appears to the right of all other apps in the dock, since the actual app itself is not in the dock. I'd like to have the app appear in the place where my automator launcher app is.
The other solution suggested in the answer above is to modify the app itself. While that would solve my issue, I'm a bit worried this will break with its auto-updater.
While the first solution is fine-ish, is there really no better solution?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
